# PDO is disable, class PDO not found in

Tags: pdo, php-ini

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in..
```

I have problem to enable my PDO, I use hostgator dedicated server.

I have contact hostgator, they said my PDO have installed.

in my php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

i have include those code, i have read many post, and try to change my php.ini but it still not work, I still got error and pdo still not working.

phpinfo

```
'--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with hostgator.

I solved this problem by enabling PHP 5.4 in the .htaccess file:

```
# enable PHP 5.4
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```